# Having a NAN output if i click my optA1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Hello everyone can anyone help me..I'm having an annoying `NAN` output if i click my `optA1` radio button...can anyone help me find whats wrong with my code.

every time i click the `optA1` i always get a result of `NAN` ...if i click the others i get a right result..why is that?

html code:

```
<td width="369"><input autocomplete="off" class="number" placeholder=" 1.)" name="name1" type="text"  value="" required size="41" id="name1" readonly /></td>

            <td width="113">
            <input id="textboxid" type="radio" name="optA1" value="1" onClick="optTotal1()" />1
            <input id="textboxid" type="radio" name="optA1" value="2" onClick="optTotal1()" />2
            <input id="textboxid" type="radio" name="optA1" value="3" onClick="optTotal1()" />3
            </td>
            <td width="109">
            <input id="textboxid" type="radio" name="optB1" value="1" onClick="optTotal1()" />1
            <input id="textboxid" type="radio" name="optB1" value="2" onClick="optTotal1()" />2
            <input id="textboxid" type="radio" name="optB1" value="3" onClick="optTotal1()" />3
            </td>
            <td width="79">
            <input id="textboxid" type="radio" name="optC1" value="1" onClick="optTotal1()" />1
            <input id="textboxid" type="radio" name="optC1" value="2" onClick="optTotal1()" />2
            </td>
            <td width="84">
            <input id="textboxid" type="radio" name="optD1" value="1" onClick="optTotal1()" />1
            <input id="textboxid" type="radio" name="optD1" value="2" onClick="optTotal1()" />2
            </td>
            <td width="53"><input class="number" id="textboxid" type="text" name="total1" onKeyUp="optTotal1()" readonly size="3" /></td>
            <td width="87"><input class="number" id="textboxid" name="remarks1" type="text"  value="" required size="8" readonly style="text-align:right;width:89px !important;"/></td>
```

script code to total:

```
<script>
function optTotal1()
{
var a1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optA1"]:checked');
var b1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optB1"]:checked');
var c1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optC1"]:checked');
var d1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optD1"]:checked');
if (a1 != null)
    a1 = parseFloat(a1.value);
else
    a1 = 0;
if (b1 != null)
    b1 = parseFloat(b1.value);
else
    b1 = 0;
if (c1 != null)
    c1 = parseFloat(c1.value);
else
    c1 = 0;
if (d1 != null)
    d1 = parseFloat(d1.value);
else
    d1 = 0;

document.frm.total1.value=parseFloat(a1)+parseFloat(b1)+parseFloat(c1)+parseFloat(d1);
}
</script>
```

Comment: parseFloat() used twice; once during individual radiobtn prcessing and once during assigning total to document.frm.total1.value

Comment: what exactly you want to do? only show a number from clicked radio input or sum of all clicked numbers. btw the id `textboxid` should be unique.

Comment: @Suman Bogati as you can see in my html and my script i want to sum all the values in the radio button i click.

Comment: Can you set up a working fiddle for it and link it here? (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @user3352395 Please have a look the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line. there is no any element named `frm`

```
document.frm.total1.value=parseFloat(a1).....
```

I suggest to use unique ids rather than same ids. like

```
textboxid1
textboxid2
textboxid3
```

To input the value into result box you can do something like this.

```
<input class="number" id="textboxid11" type="text" name="total1" onKeyUp="optTotal1()" readonly size="3" />
//-----------------put id-----^

//get the input tag by id, put result inside it
document.getElementById('textboxid11' ).value = (a1 + b1 + c1 + d1);
```

As there is no need to use `parseFloat()` twice as it's already used when contating the value.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gu9ZD/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you were getting NAN but I set up a fiddle of your code and the only thing I had to change was "document.frm.total1":

http://jsfiddle.net/vkyf6/
eg:

```
function optTotal1()
{
var a1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optA1"]:checked');
var b1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optB1"]:checked');
var c1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optC1"]:checked');
var d1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optD1"]:checked');
if (a1 != null)
    a1 = parseFloat(a1.value);
else
    a1 = 0;
if (b1 != null)
    b1 = parseFloat(b1.value);
else
    b1 = 0;
if (c1 != null)
    c1 = parseFloat(c1.value);
else
    c1 = 0;
if (d1 != null)
    d1 = parseFloat(d1.value);
else
    d1 = 0;

document.getElementById('total1').value=parseFloat(a1)+parseFloat(b1)+parseFloat(c1)+parseFloat(d1);
}
```